# How to store temporary sensitive data in memory?

Tags: windows, cmd, salt-stack

I am building an automated workflow (using Saltstack) that delivers an encrypted password to a system that needs to be joined to a domain like this:

```
netdom join %computername% /domain:domain.com /UserD:user /PasswordD:passwrd
```

The encrypted password can be decrypted and fed into above line using another script. The difficulty is with the storage of this temporary encrypted password. So far, I can only think of two ways of doing this, neither of which is desirable:

1. RAMDISK - no built-in way to create one so there is a reliance on third party, no good
2. Environmental variables - persistent variables live in registry aka on disk so still no good

Any suggestions?

Comment: A normal variable isn't persistent at all. Btw. How do you decrypt the password? If it can be done automatically, then it's still not safe

Comment: Apologies, I misspoke, it is not persistent unless made so with setx /M as far as I understand?
Regarding decryption, a random hash is used as "salt" before a one-time request for password and the same hash is used for decryption on the server. This hash is unique for each request. I am definitely no expert, but looks suitable for my need.

Comment: Ok, then you have answered your question. Don't use `setx` instead use `set`

Comment: Thanks Jeb, you are then suggesting the use of environmental variable is sufficient for this task?

Comment: How can I know that, without knowing your process nor your threat model?

Comment: Fair enough. I am still conceptualizing this process myself. Specifically for this post, I just wanted to get suggestions for medium that stores sensitive data temporarily like a ramdisk.

Comment: An environment variable (`set`) is set within the current `cmd` process (and it's children created after setting the variable) and destroyed when the corresponding process ends. It's not visible for other processes (parent or unrelated). Data in a Ramdisk can be read from anwhere. So an environment variable is more secure than a ramdisk (not bullet proof though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this password should be stored in an [encrypted pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/pillar/index.html#pillar-encryption).

```yaml
#!yaml|gpg

net_password: |
  -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
  hQEMAw2B674HRhwSAQgAhTrN8NizwUv/VunVrqa4/X8t6EUulrnhKcSeb8sZS4th
  W1Qz3K2NjL4lkUHCQHKZVx/VoZY7zsddBIFvvoGGfj8+2wjkEDwFmFjGE4DEsS74
  ZLRFIFJC1iB/O0AiQ+oU745skQkU6OEKxqavmKMrKo3rvJ8ZCXDC470+i2/Hqrp7
  +KWGmaDOO422JaSKRm5D9bQZr9oX7KqnrPG9I1+UbJyQSJdsdtquPWmeIpamEVHb
  VMDNQRjSezZ1yKC4kCWm3YQbBF76qTHzG1VlLF5qOzuGI9VkyvlMaLfMibriqY73
  zBbPzf6Bkp2+Y9qyzuveYMmwS4sEOuZL/PetqisWe9JGAWD/O+slQ2KRu9hNww06
  KMDPJRdyj5bRuBVE4hHkkP23KrYr7SuhW2vpe7O/MvWEJ9uDNegpMLhTWruGngJh
  iFndxegN9w==
  =bAuo
  -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

```yaml
join domain:
  cmd.run:
    - name: netdom join %computername% '/PasswordD:{{ pillar["net_password"] }}' /domain:domain.com /UserD:user
```

If you already have it set up in e.g. a Vault instance, you can use `sdb` to access it instead.

Comment: Thank you as usual OrangeDog. I will try this approach. If I understand correctly, looks like I can use encrypted in-line pillar too?